# Sorting an array in a foreach loop if value is not empty

Tags: php

I have this foreach loop and i was wondering if there could be a way to sort the array accurding to a value if it's not empty to be at top and the rest goes down. here what I have done so far:

```
foreach ((array)$accounts as $v=>$k){
        if(!empty($k)) {
                echo $v;
                echo "</br>";
                echo $k;
                echo "</br>";
        } else {
            echo $v;
            echo "</br>";
        }
    }
```

Note: `$k` returns either a string or it's just empty not `NULL`

The ouput is something like:

```
k1
v1
k2
k3
v3
```

As you can see `k2` has no value. i want it to be at the bottom as it doesn't have a value.

Outputing the array directly with `print_r($accounts, TRUE)`:

```
Array
(
    [TwitterSecKey] => Twitter Sec Key
    [GoogleSecKey] => 
    [InstagramSecKey] => Instagram Sec Key
    [FacebookSecKey] => 
)
```

As you can see Google and Facebook don't have values. so i want them to be at the bottom.

Comment: its better, you could have added the array, what you are trying to sort! @Alamri

Comment: `$v=>$k`...are you trying to start World War 3?! `$v` is short for `$value` and `$k` is short for `$key`.

Comment: use `asort($accounts)` before putting it in to the for each loop also no need to cast $accounts as (array) its already an array!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus help me not to bring it :)

Comment: Calling the *key* `$v`, and the *value* `$k` = war.

Comment: Can you please enlighten us by showing the output of `echo '<pre>'.print_r($accounts).'</pre>';` It will help people post good answers, I promise.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus i can't as they hold some sensitive data. but i can post an example. btw looks like Babin Kunwar got what i mean i'm going for that.

Comment: An example of the data is good too. The main thing that helps in situations like this is to see the exact structure of your key:value pairs and their nesting. Without this knowledge you should be very thankful that Nabin Kunwar was able to produce the correct answer :)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I updated the question with an example, have a look please

Comment: @Alamri I do not understand the data that you are showing; in fact it's even more confusing. Please post the output of `echo '<pre>'.print_r($accounts, TRUE).'</pre>';` but remove any sensitive data. So if one of the array elements are `[Name] => Super Top Secret CIA` then manually change it to `[Name] => Bob` when updating your question.

Comment: My apologies, it should be `echo '<pre>'.print_r($accounts, TRUE).'</pre>';`. The `TRUE` parameter is important.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus there you go

Comment: @MonkeyZeus looks like what i wanted is a well knowlegde of `uasort` Nabin Kunwar gave the answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for finally providing your array structure.

Based on your requirement of:

> sort the array accurding to a value if it's not empty to be at top and the rest goes down

There is no need for complicated sorting algorithms with `uasort()`, please try this:

```
<?php

$accounts= array(
    'TwitterSecKey'=>'Twitter Sec Key',
    'GoogleSecKey'=>null,
    'InstagramSecKey'=>'Instagram Sec Key',
    'FacebookSecKey'=>null
);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($accounts, TRUE).'</pre>';

arsort($accounts); // secret sauce

echo '<pre>'.print_r($accounts, TRUE).'</pre>';
```

---

http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Well done. accepted for being easier and more cleaner :) Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to sort your array using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and then use them accordingly

```
$accounts = (array) $accounts;
usort($accounts, function($a, $b) {
    return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
});
```

Now.

```
 foreach($accounts as $k=>$v){
       echo 'key: '. $k .'<br>';
       echo 'value: '. $v .'<br>';
     }
```

**UPDATE**
To preserve keys you can use [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) as

```
$accounts = (array) $accounts;
    uasort($accounts, function($a, $b) {
        return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
    });
```

Comment: Sir i have updated my question. can you check it again ? it could be easier to understand now

Comment: this worked but it doesn't output the key if it doesn't  have a value. also all the keys replaced with numbers.

Comment: by the way you forgot a symbol there it kinda left me lost at the begining .. if you may correct it so this answer could be useful for others and newbies like me . it's right there after the `br` just add a `>`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom function with [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php), which puts empty values last, but sorts all the rest alphabetically:

```
$accounts = array (
  'x' => 'c',
  'y' => 'a',
  'z' => 'b',
  'n' => '',
);

uasort($accounts, function($a, $b) {
    return empty($a) ? 1 : (empty($b) ? -1 : strcmp($a,$b));
});

var_export($accounts);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'y' => 'a',
  'z' => 'b',
  'x' => 'c',
  'n' => '',
)
```

Comment: Sir as you can see there should be a key and a value ?

Comment: it replaces keys with numbers... is there a way to keep the keys ?

Comment: Sure, just use `uasort` instead of `usort`. Answer updated.